# Updates to style.css are ignored (new version is live, caches cleared)

Tags: css

I updated [style.css](https://www.theveggietable.com/blog/wp-content/themes/hitmag/style.css) to get rid of table cell borders and remove transform to uppercase instructions. Loading style.css in browser shows that the new version **is** live - yet borders are still showing and text is still being transformed.

I have cleared all site / CDN / browser caches. Have tried Firefox and Chrome, including private mode.

For example, [this page](https://www.theveggietable.com/blog/vegetarian-recipes/breakfast/home-fries/):

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Please review the "*[mcve]*" guidelines, and requirements; for further information check the Meta post "[Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirm that you have a border to your table in https://hb.wpmucdn.com/www.theveggietable.com/c3e0676d-9d3a-4715-8260-1b23b8d555f7.css

```
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid #ededed;
}
```

It seems that your are using a wordpress theme , so look this way !

Comment: Thank you for leading me to yet another layer of caching. Finally fixed!